# Assign variable labels in loop

Tags: r, labelled-generic

I've got a big old dataset that I would like to programmatically label. To do so I've used the `look_for()` function from the `labelled` package to create a df of variables and labels, which I want to loop through to assign labels to my variables. Below is a simple example:

```r
library(labelled)
# create table of vars and add some labels
vlabels <- labelled::look_for(mtcars) %>%
  mutate(label = paste0("label for ", variable))
```

vlabels contents:

```r
> vlabels
 pos variable label          col_type values
 1   mpg      label for mpg  dbl            
 2   cyl      label for cyl  dbl            
 3   disp     label for disp dbl            
 4   hp       label for hp   dbl            
 5   drat     label for drat dbl            
 6   wt       label for wt   dbl            
 7   qsec     label for qsec dbl
```

Attempt to assign labels:

```r
for(v in length(vlabels$variable)){
  var = vlabels$variable[v]
  vlabel = vlabels$label[v]
  attr(mtcars[var], 'label') <- vlabel
}
```

Checking output and my labels do not appear:

```r
attr(mtcars$mpg, 'label') 
> attr(mtcars$mpg, 'label')
NULL
```

Not sure what I'm missing here except that loops are bad and I should use apply.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `var_label`:

```
library(labelled)

var_label(mtcars) <- paste0("label for ", colnames(mtcars))
var_label(mtcars)

$mpg
[1] "label for mpg"

$cyl
[1] "label for cyl"

$disp
[1] "label for disp"
...
```

You can also assign labels for each column individually:

```
var_label(mtcars$mpg) <- "Specific label for mpg"
var_label(mtcars)

var_label(mtcars)
$mpg
[1] "Specific label for mpg"

$cyl
NULL

$disp
NULL
...
```

Which leads with your original loop to:

```
for(v in 1:length(vlabels$variable)){
  var = vlabels$variable[v]
  vlabel = vlabels$label[v]
  var_label(mtcars[[var]])<-vlabel
}

var_label(mtcars)
$mpg
[1] "label for mpg"

$cyl
[1] "label for cyl"

$disp
[1] "label for disp"
...
```

Comment: Thanks, this would accomplish the task on a full list of variable-label combinations, but not the matching assignment done inside the for loop.

Comment: You can also assign labels individually : `var_label(mtcars$mpg) <- "test"`

Comment: See my latest edit : the loop you wrote only modifies element 11 = `length(vlabels$variable)`. You forgot `1:length(...)`